# Forcing parameter to function to be more generic using <any>

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

Whenever I try to do this, I can't get it to work, I have this code:

```
router.events.subscribe(val => {
  console.log('router event:', val);
  localStorage.setItem(this.anyRouteKey, val.url);
});
```

it's giving me this error:

[image]

it turns out, the `url` property does exist, it's just an error in the typings. So I want to cast val to `Object` or `any`, for the short term. So I try to do that, but nothing I try works:

[image]

[image]

What is the right way to cast the input parameter to any?

Comment: note that router is an instance of Router, like so: https://gist.github.com/ORESoftware/01145b18a239b2ba7f0f1cbb0c8fccf8

Comment: Using latest angular ?

Comment: Did you try `(val: any) => { ... }` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not an error in the typings, `val` is of type `Event` which is a union type of `RouterEvent | RouteConfigLoadStart | RouteConfigLoadEnd | ChildActivationStart | ChildActivationEnd | ActivationStart | ActivationEnd` and only some of these have the `url` property. Union types allow access only to common properties, and `url` is not common to all;

If you are using typescript 2.6, you can use the `in` type guard:

```
router.events.subscribe(val => {
    if('url' in val) {
        console.log(val.url);
    }
});
```

Another option is to type the parameter to the lambda explicitly with the type of event that actually has the `url` property (provided you don't use the `strictFunctionTypes` compiler flag in 2.6)

```
router.events.subscribe((val : RouterEvent) => {
    console.log(val.url);
});
```

Or if you really want to go the `any` route:

```
router.events.subscribe((val : any) => {
    console.log(val.url);
});
```